# Javascript- to randomize an array of functions

Tags: javascript, html

This is a javascript code. I have a collection of 10 functions **card11()** to **card25()**. On-click in another HTML code, I want **one** of these functions to be called randomly. I applied the following logic, but it seems to be flawed. HELP, please!

```
 arr=[card11(), card12(), card13(), card14(), card15(), card21(), card22(), card23() , card24(), card25()];
    function myFunc(arr)
    {
      var d, c, b = arr.length;
      while (b)
      {
          c = Math.floor(Math.random() * b);
          d = arr[--b];
          arr[b] = arr[c];
          arr[c] = d;
      }
           return arr;
    }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but those seem to be variations of the same function. Have you considered making a single more generic function with a parameter instead of the 10 you have now?

Comment: Umm I do not know how I can do that. The functions are pretty complex.

Comment: Perhaps you could post on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you think the problem is interesting enough. Make sure the code is working first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the array should contain references to the function instead of executing the function:

```
var arr=[card11, card12, card13, card14, card15, card21, card22, card23 , card24, card25];
```

Next, you can easily call a random function that array using this function:

```
function callRandom(arr){
    arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]();
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
function func1(){
    alert("func2");
}
function func2(){
    alert("func1");
}
function func3(){
    alert("func1");
}

var arr = [func1, func2, func3];


function callRandom(arr){
    arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]();
}

callRandom(arr);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cqLLV/1/

Comment: <td> <img src="card.jpg" id="a" onclick="myFunc(arr)"> </td>

Would this be the right way to call it in HTML? I do not know what to pass as a parameter, since I am defining the array in the script file.

Comment: @user3193046 You should attach the event with `addEventListener` instead of inlining the handler.

Comment: No, I got it! I just declared the array locally inside the function and didnt pass any parameters. Its working fine now. Thank you!